# Does a string from mySQL match the same string specified manually?

Tags: mysql, md5, gravatar

Trying to implement gravatar on a site. Here's the code to return the gravatar link.

```
function getGravatar(){
    $email = $userInfo['email'];
    $trimmed = trim($email);
    $md5 = md5(strtolower($trimmed));
    $gravatar = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" . $md5;
    return $gravatar;
}
```

The above code doesn't work, but it does work if I replace `$email = $userInfo['email'];` with `$email = "crumrinece@gmail.com";` (the email associated with the gravatar). In both cases, I echoed $md5, and found that the hash was different for each case.

I assumed that meant I had a problem with $userInfo['email'], but `echo $userInfo['email']` printed "crumrinece@gmail.com". So i'm at a loss as to why the two produce different hash values.

The email is stored in a MySql database. The code to generate $userInfo:

```
$query = "select * from users where username = '$username'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$userInfo = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Comment: is this the real code you are using? `$userInfo` is not defined in the scope of `getGravatar()`. There is no `global` keyword to import the variable from the global scope and there is no parameter for the function, too. Where does `$userInfo` come from?

Answer (score 0):

When you echo `$userInfo['email']` the browser won't show you non-printable characters or HTML code the expression might contain. You can check the hex dump for any unexpected bytes:

```
echo bin2hex($userInfo['email'])
```

Answer (score 0):

A different encoding can lead to different hashes, even if the strings look the same when displayed. The query maybe returns a unicode string. Check the database encoding and take a look at  [`utf8_decode()`](http://php.net/function.utf8-decode) (or maybe [`iconv()`](http://php.net/function.iconv) or [`mb_convert_encoding()`](http://php.net/function.mb-convert-encoding)) to convert the address if necessary.

```
$email = utf8_decode($userInfo['email']);
```

Comment: "crumrinece@gmail.com" does not contain any UTF-8 character. even if stored in a UTF-8 collation, the used characters are part of the ASCII compatible UTF-8 codeset

Comment: Oh my word, Kaii was absolutely right, I simply forgot to declare $userInfo as a global inside getGravatar. Thank you. Can't believe I did that.